# knockout, mapping plugin to append child nodes to a parent element

Tags: javascript, for-loop, knockout.js, parent-child

Let's say for example, that we have parent elements and corresponding child elements.
So, I have a parent class and a child class in javascript :

// Class to represent a parent

```
function parent(data) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name); 
    this.children = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

// Class to represent a child

```
function child(data) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id); 
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.Age = ko.observable(data.Age);
    this.ParentID = ko.observable(data.ParentID);
}
```

Actually, I'm able to attach children related to each parent by doing

```
    Jquery.getJSON("/api/parents", function (allData) {
        var mappedParents = Jquery.map(allData, function (item) { 
            return new parent(item) 
        });
        self.parents(mappedParents);

        // Get Children and attach them to the corresponding parent
        Jquery.getJSON("/api/children", function (allData) {
            var mappedChildren = Jquery.map(allData, function (item) { 
            return new child(item) 
        });
        self.children(mappedChildren);

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(mappedChildren, function (dataChildren) {
            var children_ParentID = dataChildren.ParentID();
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.parents(), function (parent) {
                if (parent.Id() == children_ParentID) {
                    parent.children.push(new child(dataChildren));
                }
            });
        });
    });

    });
```

and I finally get a Json containing observable arrays of children related to each parent.

```
parent :
[   
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Parent1", 
        "children": [
            {"Id": 1, "Name": "Child11", "Age": "11", "ParentID": 1},
            {"Id": 2, "Name": "Child12", "Age": "12", "ParentID": 1},
            {"Id": 3, "Name": "Child13", "Age": "13", "ParentID": 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Parent2", 
        "children": [
            {"Id": 4, "Name": "Child11", "Age": "21", "ParentID": 2},
            {"Id": 5, "Name": "Child12", "Age": "22", "ParentID": 2}
        ]
    } 
]
```

So, as you can see, I'm able to attach children to a given parent by a nested loop

```
foreach parents 
{ 
   var idParent = Id;
   foreach children 
   {
      if chidren.parentId == idParent then attach children
   } 
}
```

But, I'm sure, there may be a better way to do this, which is more efficient. For example, the mapping plugin ? or something better ? Because if there's lot of data, it may take time to pull all children to each parent.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach suggests to get all the children first and then get all the parents. Then filtering the children for a particular parent from the original children array.

```
var parent = function(data) {
  var myself = this;
  this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id); //I assume this is same as the parentId property in a child object.
  this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  this.children = ko.observableArray(self.getChildByParentId(this.Id));
}

var child = function(data) {
  var myself = this;
  this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  this.Age = ko.observable(data.Age);
  this.ParentID = ko.observable(data.ParentID);
}

self.getChildByParentId = function(parentId) {
  var children = ko.utils.ArrayFilter(self.children(), function(child) {
    return child.ParentId === parentId;
  });
  return children;
}

Jquery.getJSON("/api/children", function(allData) {
  var mappedChildren = Jquery.map(allData, function(item) {
    return new child(item);
  });
  self.children(mappedChildren);
});

Jquery.getJSON("/api/parents", function(allData) {
  var mappedParents = Jquery.map(allData, function(item) {
    return new parent(item);
  });
  self.parents(mappedParents);
});
```

I am still not sure whether this is what you expect as an answer, but still can be given a shot...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to put **Jquery.getJSON("/api/children", function (allData) { ..}**  inside **Jquery.getJSON("/api/parent", function (allData) { ..}** otherwise my screen doesn't ALWAYS display parent elements as well as child elements. Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't !     But may be, I have to query the database each time I want children related to a given parent instead of loading all of them into the browser. I'll give it a try

Comment: I had this assumption that these api calls are independent of each other....anyways, when do you actually fetch the child data really depends on the underlying business logic.....

Comment: I strongly suggest you use maping plugin. I use it for years and help a lot.

Comment: @fabiosilvalima - any specific mapping plugin apart from what OP has used and knockout's mapping plugin(of course)